# Edit Gridview cell value based on it's value (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm displaying a table in a Gridview. Some fields contain `0` and `1`, but mean `Yes` and `No`. When displaying the table in a Gridview I would like to edit the `0's` and `1's` to show `Yes` or `No`.

Any suggestions on how this could work?

Thanks!

---

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Gearchiveerd?" InsertVisible="false" DataField="BestellingGearchiveerd" SortExpression="BestellingGearchiveerd">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Gearchiveerd? = Header

BestellingGearchiveerd = column name

Comment: have you set the autogeneratecolumns false for gridview?

Comment: Yes, I have turned it off and created my own set of tables that I want. I have already been able to edit the empty cells and date cells, but I don't know how to add an if-else cause to it. (or whatever I need to get it to work)

Comment: Usage of the Table word is incorrect. Rather it should be replaced with columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below implementation. This might really help you.

Design

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Yes/No">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblYesNo" Text='<%#GetText(Eval("BitColumnName")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

C# Code

```
protected string GetText(object value)
{
    int textValue;
    if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(value), out textValue))
    {
        if (textValue == 0)
            return "No";
        else
            return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        return "&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

VB Code

```
Protected Function GetText(value As Object) As String
    Dim textValue As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(Convert.ToString(value), textValue) Then
        If textValue = 0 Then
            Return "No"
        Else
            Return "Yes"
        End If
    Else
        Return "&nbsp;"
    End If
End Function
```

You can change the Yes and No as required. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry, this is C#, I should have mentioned I'm using VB.NET coding.

Comment: You can handle all the cases in the GetText Method or Function as per your requirement. :)

Comment: What if I have a BoundField? Look at my original post.

Comment: Then you need to write your custom code in RowDataBound or RowCreated Events. Rather I would prefer of using a Template field as it saves lot of coding :)

Comment: I would suggest of exploring yourself on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to change 1 or 0 to yes or no with string.format, but you may want to look at the DataFormatString property of the bound field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

EDIT: Here is additional info w/ possible solutions:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1127044.aspx/1?Boolean+Format+String+Yes+No+instead+of+True+False